# generators and stream_template in Flask

Tags: flask, generator

My goal is to stream chunks from the OpenAI API into a Flask app. I've managed to stream the chunks into the HTML template as desired, but I'm encountering issues in saving all the chunks into a variable that aggregates them all.

Code:

```
def EPQA(query):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages =[{'role':'user', 'content': query}],
        temperature = 0,
        stream = True)
    
    return response

def stream_EPQA(query):
    resp_entire = []
    response=EPQA(query=query)
    
    for r in response:
        if r.choices[0].delta:
            resp=r.choices[0].delta.content
            resp_entire.append(resp)
            yield resp



@app.route('/<safe_url>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home(safe_url):
    form = query_form()      

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        query=form.query.data

        resp = stream_EPQA(query=query)          
       #i need a variable aggregating all the streamed chunks
    else:
        query = ''
        resp = ''
        
    return stream_template('home.html', form=form,  d_form=d_form, query=query,
                                    resp=resp, safe_url=safe_url)
```

I tried to create a variable that aggregates the chunks in this way:

```
resp = ''.join(stream_EPQA(query=query))
```

However, in this way, the chunks are not streamed and transmitted all together to the HTML once the generator is completed.

I also tried to create a second variable:

```
resp = stream_EPQA(query=query)
resp_entire = list(resp)
```

But in this way, it seems like the generator is not transmitted to the HTML, and no chunks are printed in the HTML.

On the other hand, this approach works:

```
resp = stream_EPQA(query=query)
resp_entire = list(stream_EPQA(query=query))
```

But I make two calls to OpenAI in this way.